# Combining 2 SQL statements into 1

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to select employees who earns more than their managers. I have these SQL statements I wrote below, but how exactly would I combine these to make one statement?

```
SELECT E.Salary
FROM Employee E
WHERE E.ManagerId = E.Id

SELECT *
FROM Employee M
WHERE M.Salary > E.Salary AND M.ManagerId != M.Id
```

Comment: Your first query returns salaries of people who manage themselves, which is not a part of selecting "employees who earns more than their managers". Your second query is not a valid SQL statement since E is undefined. PS See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33952141/3404097) re querying.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT E.Salary, M.*
FROM Employee E
 inner join Mamanger M on E.ManagerId = M.Id and E.Salary > M.Salary
```

Answer (score 2):

you could use a self inner join

```
SELECT E.*
FROM Employee E
INNER JOIN Employee M ON  E.ManagerId = M.Id
WHERE E.Salary > M.Salary
```

Answer (score 1):

Read about joining, for your example:

```
SELECT E.* 
FROM Employee E 
    JOIN Employee M ON E.ManagerId = M.Id 
WHERE E.Salary>M.Salary;
```